Даёт ли TeamViewer пояснение о завершённом-оборванном сеансе, если ПК был выключен или перезагружен с этой программы?
Известно что, в процессе работы, программа TeamViewer маячит у управляемого компьютера в трее и на самом экране, в виде либо окошка самой проги, либо, при сворачивании окна, в виде стрелочки. Также известно что программа сообщает управляемому ПК о завершении сеанса. Но когда компьютер отключается или перезагружается с TeamViewer'а, даёт ли программа(при её следующем запуске)понять что с неё ПК был выключен или перезагружен?. Или эта информация будет только в логах и никакой заметки TeamViewer сам не даст?.
